# WebStorm incorrectly shows unresolved method in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have installed WebStorm 2019.3 and there is a weird unresolved function warning for a `bcryptjs` library. The project is Node.js and I did `npm install`.

There are other dependencies working fine but this particular does not. Any idea?

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(uri) // OK, not highlighted
const token = jwt.sign({ // OK, not highlighted

if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) { // KO, highlighted as unresolved
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try un-excluding `node_modules\bcryptjs\dist` folder: right-click it, choose **Mark directory As/Not Excluded**; re-open the project.

I'd also suggest installing `bcryptjs` typings for better coding assistance: put cursor on `'bcryptjs'` in `require('bcryptjs')`, hit `Alt+Enter`, choose **Install Typescript definitions for better type informaion**.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

[image]

Comment: Thank you, installing the typescript definitions made a difference!